# Select layer by location in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, select-by-location

I have a footprint of some buildings (see the picture).
[image: Building footprint]

The selected buildings have an area below 30 sqm. 
As you can in the picture see some buildings share almost borders with a building bigger than 30 sqm. When others don't.
The building below 30 sqm but shares a border with a bigger building I want to include in my calculation. The others below 30 sqm should be sorted away.

I have succeeded with this through desktop GIS, and the solution looks like this:
[image: Modelbuilder function]

But I want to do the same process in postgres.

I can select the buildings pending on their area and I have put them in to two new tables:

`Create TABLE building_below as
 Select * from building where area<30`
and 
`Create TABLE building_above as
Select * from building where area>30`

I can not figure out how to select layer by location in PostgreSQL.

I have tried with inspiration from:
[Join polygons by location PostgreSQL/PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219618/join-polygons-by-location-postgresql-postgis)
[Merging adjacent polygons in shapefile that has been split at tile boundaries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50290/merging-adjacent-polygons-in-shapefile-that-has-been-split-at-tile-boundaries)

But it didn't work.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.gid) s.gid,*

 FROM building_below s

LEFT JOIN building_above h ON ST_DWithin(s.geom, h.geom, 0.01)

ORDER BY s.gid, ST_Distance(s.geom, h.geom);
```

But it just select all the rows/buildings in building_below.

I know from desktop GIS, that it should not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT a.*
FROM  building AS a
JOIN  building AS b
  ON  ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
WHERE a.area <= 30
  AND b.area > 30;
```

Make sure you have a spatial index in place and run `VACUUM ANALYZE building;` prior to execution!

If your buildings only *almost* share a border, i.e. don't actually intersect, use

`... ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, <threshold>) ...`

instead.

Note that the latter will need your `geom` either projected or in type `GEOGRAPHY` to make sense (i.e. if your `geom` is in EPSG:4326 or any geographic CRS, units will be in degrees and thus rather useless. You can then, if in EPSG:4326, however, easily cast to `GEOGRAPHY` to implicitly use meter as unit).

Comment: My Geom is in 4326. 
But the area is calculated in 25832. 
What should do then? 
When I run this:

`
SELECT *
FROM  bygning AS B
JOIN  bygning AS D 
  ON  public.ST_Dwithin(B.geom, D.geom, 0.5)
WHERE B.area_25832 <= 30
  AND D.area_25832 > 30;`

It returns +300 rows, and their is only 60 polygons.

Comment: `ST_DWithin(B.geom::GEOGRAPHY, D.geom::GEOGRAPHY, 0.5) ...` will find geometries within 0.5 *meter*. problem now is that the index on `GEOMETRY` cannot be used; either create a functional spatial index `... ON (CAST(geom, GEOGRAPHY)) ...` on both tables, create one `... ON (ST_Transform(geom, 25832)) ...` on both tables and transform on-the-fly, or reproject (or retype) and reindex both tables into EPSG:25832 (or `GEOGRAPHY`). you *could* try without all that and using 0.000005 (degrees) maybe...but that's a last resort.

Comment: I have tried the following sentence;    <--alter table bygning add column geom_25832 geography;
update bygning set geom_25832=(ST_Transform(geom, 25832))>    
the output is: ERROR:  Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography. I guess, i am not sure, what you want me to do?

Comment: @N.Juul the `GEOGRAPHY` type needs the geometries in EPSG:4326 (-> WGS 84 lat/lons): if your initial geometries are EPSG:4326, I'd suggest to just add a functional index with a cast: `CREATE INDEX bygning_geog_idx ON bygning USING GIST (CAST(geom, GEOGRAPHY));`

Comment: I have tried this:

drop index bygning_geog_idx;
CREATE INDEX bygning_geog_idx ON bygning USING GIST (CAST(geom as GEOGRAPHY));

SELECT *
FROM  bygning AS a
JOIN  bygning AS b
  ON  ST_Dwithin(a.geom, b.geom)
WHERE a.area <= 30
  AND b.area > 30;

And I have run the vacuum analyze in prior.

But it still does not work. 

I have one table buildings, with a geom in EPSG:4326. 
I have two tables with buidlings below 30 sqm and above 30 sqm. 

Buildings below 30 sqm, but within 0,5 meters from a building above 30 sqm, should also be a part of the calculation. 

How to do that?

Comment: @N.Juul assuming your `geom` column is still type `GEOMETRY` and referenced in EPSG:4326, and you did add that index, you'd have to then cast the `geom` to `GEOGRAPHY`: --> `SELECT * FROM bygning AS a JOIN bygning AS b ON ST_DWithin(a.geom::GEOGRAPHY, b.geom::GEOGRAPHY, 0.5) WHERE a.area <= 30 AND b.area > 30;`

Comment: With your help, i have make it work - almost!
I select the buildings thats below 30 sqm, and within 0,5m from a building above 30 sqm. 
I want to put this into a table with buildings above 30sqm - this should be pretty easy, but it does not work.

      'I have this code:
      --create table bygning_30 as
      --select * from bygning where area_25832>30;
      insert into bygning_30
      SELECT *
      FROM  bygning AS a
     JOIN  bygning AS b
     ON  ST_DWithin(a.geom::GEOGRAPHY, b.geom::GEOGRAPHY, 0.5)
     WHERE a.area_25832 <= 30 
     and b.area_25832 >30

Comment: @N.Juul what's the problem? any errors? how about `CREATE TABLE bygning_30 AS SELECT * FROM bygning WHERE area_25832 > 30 UNION ALL SELECT a.* FROM bygning AS a JOIN bygning AS b ON ST_DWithin(a.geom::GEOGRAPHY, b.geom::GEOGRAPHY, 0.5) WHERE a.area_25832 <= 30 AND b.area_25832 > 30;`

Comment: In my solution it says the error is: ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 1: insert into bygning_30 SELECT * FROM bygning AS a JOIN bygni...
When I run your solution the error is:

ERROR:  each UNION query must have the same number of columns
LINE 4: UNION ALL SELECT * FROM bygning AS a JOIN bygning AS b

Comment: @N.Juul ...ah yes, I forgot one thing: you will need to specify the table from which to select the columns! in your example (and mine thus far), `SELECT * FROM ...` will select **all columns from both tables of the join**, i.e. it duplicates the same columns in this case of a self-join. I updated the answer, and the query in the comment I just wrote, with `SELECT a.* FROM ...`.

Comment: Perfect! It works - thanks for your patience and help!!! My project group appreciates that!